# How can I export a Map to reuse in other components?

Tags: angular, typescript

Say I have an enum declared like so

```
export enum SomeEnum {
SomeLongName = 1,
AnotherName = 2
}
```

In my display components I am using an enum map to map the enum values into strings for displaying in my web app:

```
enumMap = new Map<number, string>([
[SomeEnum.SomeLongName, 'Some long name.'],
[SomeEnum.AnotherName, 'Another name.']
]);
```

This all works fine. The problem is I would like to reuse this map in my other components, but if I try declaring it in my `whatever.model.ts` file, I get the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: iterable for Map should have array-like objects`

I am exporting it like so:

```
export const SomeEnumMap = new Map<number, string>([
[SomeEnum.SomeLongName, 'Some long name.'],
[SomeEnum.AnotherName, 'Another name.']
])
```

and in my `whatever.component.ts`:

```
import { SomeEnumMap } from './whatever.model.ts';

export class SomeClassComponent implements OnInit {

map = SomeEnumMap;
----------
```

Is there a way I can export it properly so I can reuse it? Everything works fine when I create the map in the component itself, but attempting to export it from the model throws an error. Google and the docs aren't being very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was being stupid. But I'm going to leave the question up since this was not something that was picked up by the linter. I was missing a comma between one of the pairs in my EnumMap, which made the map not iterable. Adding it in fixed the error!